# Cordova application considerably slower than mobile browser version of application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

We have a web application that we've recently wrapped with Cordova. That being said, the overall experience is considerably slower from the web equivalent. What are the reasons for this?

Some examples include transitions, animations, touch interactions, etc.

I haven't been able to get `--prod` to work just yet, but I've only read that this feature improves build/start time of the application. Not sure about UI/UX interactions.

Comment: FYI this solved our problem for iOS https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine :)

Answer (score 0):

How are your transitions setup? Jquery, CSS?

Are you using `box-shadow`? That can cause the slow animations.

Please provide some code examples.